# Providing Catalog Service for Web (CSW) using ArcGIS software?

Tags: arcgis-server, arccatalog, arcims, csw, esri-geoportal-server

I need to harvest catalog data from a ArcGIS database, and as I understand it, a [Catalog Service for the Web (CSW)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalog_Service_for_the_Web) should be the way to go. [Some](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//003700000002000000.htm) docs mention vaguely the "GIS Portal Toolkit" or the (discontinued) "ArcIMS". [Others](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Catalog-Service) mention the [Geoportal Server](http://geoportal.sourceforge.net/).

**What is the recommended way of providing catalog data as CSW using ArcGIS?** Namely, which components should I use, and where can I find concrete/detailed instructions on how to do it?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info on why you want to harvest catalog data from ArcGIS.  Is there ArcGIS Server already involved?  For CSW support, your right with looking at GeoPortal server, but it might be that looking at the REST endpoint for site catalog or using a search service in ArcGIS Server might be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, there is an ArcGIS server involved, but I am not familiar with its specific setup yet. I hypothesize that we may need to instal something more on ArcGIS side to be able to harvest the data, but all the better if we don't. On the outside, GeoPortal looks way more than what I need. The protocol doesn't necessarily have to be CSW, although that would make things easier for me on the harvester side, which already supports it. It can be extended to harvest from other sources though. Thanks for your pointers, I will look into the REST endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [SOAP SDK](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/soap/10.1/index.html#//01vp0000009s000000):

> An ArcGIS Server instance maintains a list of services and their
>   properties, such as name, type, and folder. The Catalog service
>   enables you to traverse and explore the services exposed by an ArcGIS
>   Server instance.

Comment: You mean, I can use it to discover where I may find an (eventually) available CSW endpoint on my server? Or that it provides what I need to do the harvesting and that I should use it *instead* of CSW.

Comment: I think the latter is intended.  AFAIK it is not possible to configure a CSW endpoint on an ArcGIS server instance.  GeoPortal gives you the ability to consume a CSW service (not serve one)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try here
https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/geoportal-server/common-questions

another option, if you have direct access to the database, is to ignore ArcServer altogether, install Geoserver and see if you can get that to expose OGC CSW services. Depends on how much flexibility you have. Geoportal is opensource though, so start at the above link, its got links to the GitHub.